# Detect scroll distance to execute a parallaxScroll effect

Tags: jquery, parallax

So here's my problem. I want `aside figure.deux` (an image) to start appearing from the bottom of the screen when the scroll down hit [X]% of the page (using % because I want my page to be responsive to the size of the screen), and I also want `aside figure.deux` to stop scrolling up when scroll down hit [Y]% of the page and start scrolling back down until it disappear. But being new at jQuery I have no idea how to do that.

Wonder if anyone could come up with some sample jQuery code that would solve my problem.

Here's the HTML and CSS of `aside figure.deux`

HTML

```
<aside>
     <figure class="deux">
    <img src="images/image_2.png"alt="Foret">
</figure>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
aside figure.deux {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-100%;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Your image tag is broken. `<img src="images/image_2.png" alt="Foret" />`

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @nderscore How can you say its broken?

Comment: I fixed it. I was missing the ">" at the end..